# How to Generate row number as same as inserted without create or insert or cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've this script:

```
Create table #temp (id int,name varchar(10),city varchar(10),sal int)
Insert into #temp
Select 2,'kishor','hyd', 100
Union all
Select 3,'kumar','sec', 200
Union all
Select 4,'santosh','kp', 300
Union all
Select 1,'sudeep','myp', 300
```

now I want to generate row number as same as data inserted without using a create or insert or CTE or Update commands, using a single select statement.
So that even after sorting by any order the row number column should not change its values

Comment: Tables have no inherent order. If you need a particular order, you need to identify a column that has that information, or would produce your desired order if we were to sort by that column. If you don't currently have such a column, you need to add one. (Of course, all previous references to a column could also be a group of columns)

Answer (score 0):

You should add auto-increment field to your table to save information about inserting order. 
And then use for example [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get a rownumber:

```
select #temp.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (order by <your autoincrement field here> ) as RowNumber
       from #temp
```